# mysql multiple left join update

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE  p.id_product, p.quantity, p.price,p.on_sale, p.additional_shipping_cost, p.active,
                        p.available_for_order, p.show_price, p.date_upd,
                        pl.id_product, pl.name,pl.description, pl.description_short,
                        cl.id_category, cl.name,
                        ps.is_product,ps.price
                    LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
                    LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON (p.id_category_default = cl.id_category)
                    LEFT JOIN ps_product_shop ps ON (p.id_category_default = ps.id_product)

                SET     
                        p.quantity = \"$quantity\", 
                        p.price = \"$price\", 
                        p.additional_shipping_cost = \"$additional_shipping_cost\",
                        p.active = \"$active\", 
                        p.available_for_order = \"$available_for_order\", 
                        p.show_price = \"$show_price\",
                        pl.name=\"$name\", 
                        pl.description=\"$description\",
                        pl.description_short=\"$description_short\",
                        p.date_upd = NOW(),
                        cs.price=\"$price\", 
                        cs.date_upd = NOW() 
                WHERE p.id_product = $i
```

Comment: What exactly do you want?
Welcome to StackOverflow, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: You do not appear to have specified what the table aliased as p is. You appear to have a long list of fields on p, then a join to ps_product_land and then the set statement. The long list of fields is not required but the table is

Comment: LEFT JOINs on UPDATE queries do happen - but they're rare.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @HamZa i think he does not understand the syntax of the update statement...

Comment: you are missing table with alias `p`

Comment: @SQL.injection Whether he understands everything or not, there is no question. I won't even read his code and vote close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct [syntax of the update statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is

```
update FooTable 
 set fooField1 = fooValue
where foofield2 = fooCondition
```

so, your query must look like something like this, with **no selection** of the fields...

```
UPDATE  FooTable p
                    LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
                    LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON (p.id_category_default = cl.id_category)
                    LEFT JOIN ps_product_shop ps ON (p.id_category_default = ps.id_product)

                SET     
                        p.quantity = \"$quantity\", 
                        p.price = \"$price\", 
                        p.additional_shipping_cost = \"$additional_shipping_cost\",
                        p.active = \"$active\", 
                        p.available_for_order = \"$available_for_order\", 
                        p.show_price = \"$show_price\",
                        pl.name=\"$name\", 
                        pl.description=\"$description\",
                        pl.description_short=\"$description_short\",
                        p.date_upd = NOW(),
                        cs.price=\"$price\", 
                        cs.date_upd = NOW() 
                WHERE p.id_product = $i
```

Comment: i am getting error. Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: that is a php error, not a mysql error...